# Executing bat file via Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, batch-file

How to run a local bat file on a js button click using Chrome browser ?

'window.open('file:///C:/Test/Test.bat' - Opens the bat file contents in a new tab instead of executing the file. It works fine in IE browser. Please suggest how to achieve this in chrome without using any plugins.

Comment: Fortunately, you **can not do this**. The security implications would be catastrophic if hackers could do this!!! It's absolutely frightening that this apparently works in IE (surely not IE11!!! must be like IE6 or something)

Comment: Seems like it works in IE 11 https://github.com/tork-a/openrtm_tutorial/issues/5#issuecomment-38724314

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for reply. No in IE 11 it works. It is just a local html file trying to run a bat file available in local machine. If I install a plugin called 'Local Explorer' then even in chrome it works. - window.open('localexplorer:C:/Test/Test.bat'. But I dont want to achieve this using a third party plugin.

Comment: @Webbanditten Yup, but I want it to work in Chrome also.

Comment: well, you'll need to use a plugin if you want to do that on your computer ... if you want to do that on other peoples computers, then, convince them to install the plugin ... it's called "security" for a reason

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, as I said it is possible using a plugin, I am not sure whether my org security team will be ok to allow all the users to have the plugin enabled. :/

Comment: fortunately, there is absolutely no workaround for the insanely insecure thing you want to do - otherwise the internet would belong to the hackers - stick to IE11 - it's a huge security hole anyway, so there's nothing you can do to make it any worse

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do  that. 
Otherwise it would be a security problems because hackers could use it to do malicious things on our computer.